# Add to NODE_PATH on Heroku/Foreman

Tags: node.js, heroku, foreman

Is it possible to add NODE_PATH in Heroku/Foreman, I can't seem to find anything in the docs, and I'd like to load custom modules from my `lib` directory.

I've tried the following in my .env file and loaded it locally with Foreman and it doesn't seem to work:

```
NODE_PATH=/path/to/lib/directory
```

The environment variable gets loaded but not picked up by Node as I get `module not found` errors.

Answer (score 1):

Two options here, add export the the beginning of your variable declaration:

```
export NODE_PATH=/path/to/lib/directory
```

Without export the variable is only available within the shell and not available to sub processes

Option 2, prefix your foreman start with the declaration of the variable

```
NODE_PATH=/path/to/lib/directory foreman start
```

This will make the variable available within the foreman process and it's child processes